# How do we determine an array type in C# using VTSO in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel-2016

I was wondering whether it is possible to determine array type from a Value2 range. For example, if we have only numbers occupying cells A1 to A5 in Excel. Each cell is then actually a double in C# VTSO.

However, if we read it using the following line:

```
object t = Application.get_Range("A1:A5").Value2;
```

We can determine that t is actually an array. So, we can do:

```
object[,] t = Application.get_Range("A1:A5").Value2;
```

To read the individual items of the array. But how do we determine the array type?

The only method that I can think of is trying to cast it to double[,] or string[,] and then wrap it in a try catch statement.
Or is it the case that if I do string[,] always going to succeed in Excel?

I realize that directly casting it from object[,] to string[,] for example does not work. I guess, you need to change it per element.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that array is type of variant (object in c#), which can hold any type of data. Note, that a try to convert this array into specific type of data may failed, because `A1:A5` range can hold different data types.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can just use `var` keyword.

So: `var t = Application.get_Range("A1:A5").Value2;`

To retype the objects in `t`, you have to do it manually for each object. Just cast the object to the type that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct compile-time type for [`Value2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx) you can safely assume is `object`. Any other assumption will yield very brittle code. You must  explicitly state your intent based on the run-time type of each cell. That said, calling `Value2` directly on the `get_Range` result is probably not what you want to do anyway.

Instead, iterate over the returned range (it's 1-based):

```
var targetRange = Application.get_Range("A1:A5");
for (int i = 1; i <= targetRange.Count; i++)
{
  // Range Item returns... Range! Gotta love this API...
  var range = (Range)targetRange.Item[i];
  object value = range.Value2;

  // Test-and-cast
  if (value is string) {
     var strValue = (string)value;
     // Do string things
  }
  elseif (value is double) {
     var dValue = (double)value;
     // Do double things
  }
  (...)

  // For C#7 or above, use 'pattern matching switch' instead of above test-and-cast
  switch(value) {
     case string strValue:
        // Do string things
        break;
     case double dValue:
        // Do double things
        break;
     (...)
  }
}
```

On an side note, do not be tempted to use `foreach` or `linq` `Cast()` when working on the range, stick to the `for` loop above. Foreach/Linq may work at first glance (well it *might* work for the life time of your app), but they both use `GetEnumerator()`, which is leaky in the office API unless you do memory management correctly, and it's just messy.